# Compute Average response time on hourly basis

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I am trying to calculate avg response time on hourly basis from the log file which has millions of records, below has the excerpt from log

As of now I am trying with creating temproary file which will have lines with unique id and start time and end time and after that another script will run on this temp file to calcualte avg response time for each hour
My script takes more than an hour to create temp file.

Is there any way we can do it quicker? or better script whose exceution time is lesser.
Note:These UNIQID is not coming in sequence.

```
log file format
2012-06-04 13:04:19,324 UNIQID1
2012-06-04 13:04:20,120 UNIQID1
2012-06-04 13:05:19,324 UNIQID2
2012-06-04 13:06:20,120 UNIQID2
2012-06-04 13:07:19,324 UNIQID3
2012-06-04 13:08:20,120 UNIQID3
2012-06-04 13:08:49,324 UNIQID4
2012-06-04 13:09:50,120 UNIQID4
```

Here is my code:

```
uids=`cat $i|grep "UNIQ" |sort -u` >> $log
for uid in ${uids}; do  
    count=`grep "$uid" test.log|wc -l`
    if [ "${count}" -ne "0" ]; then
        unique_uids[counter]="$uid"
        let counter=counter+1   
    fi   
done


echo ${unique_uids[@]}   
echo $counter  
echo " Unique No:" ${#unique_uids[@]}
echo uid StartTime EndTime" > $log

for unique_uids in ${unique_uids[@]} ; do
    responseTime=`cat $i|grep "${unique_uids}" |awk '{split($2,Arr,":|,"); print Arr[1]*3600000+Arr[2]*60000+Arr[3]*1000+Arr[4]}'|sort -n`
    echo $unique_uids $responseTime >> $log
done
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: This belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Are you running on a Linux system with Gnu awk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some simple fixes:

- You don't need the [`cat`](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html) calls; simply use the file name as the last parameter to `grep`.
- You shouldn't save values to *both* a file and a variable; use whichever is faster. Usually you don't have to use either; a `while IFS= read -r date time id` loop will probably be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Your script has several issues and I think you'll find something like the one below to be better suited to your needs. First, you don't need to be spawning all those processes to do the work - its fairly straightforward to do it all inside awk. Furthermore, the code you posted assumes that a particular UNIQID will occur only on the same date. This assumption will cause much grief if your records wrap around midnight to the next day.

The following code does what you want inside an `awk` script. It assumes you are using `gawk` (Gnu awk). If you aren't, you can find `awk` implementations of mktime on the web [including here](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_16.html#SEC147)

```
BEGIN {
  while (getline < UIDFILE) {
    x[$0] = 1;          # Awk will maintain these as an associative array, lookups are hashed
  }
}


{
  r = $NF;                  # Extract the unique ID from the record into r
  if (r in x) {             # If the UID is something we are interested in, then ...
    ts = $1 " " $2;         # concatenate these fields
    gsub ("[:-]", " ", ts); # Replace the : and - with spaces 
    gsub (",.*", "", ts);   # Remove everything after the comma
    # print ts, mktime(ts)  # If you want to see what mktime does 

    if (x[r] == "")         # First time seeing this unique ID?
      x[r] = mktime(ts);    # Store the timestamp
    else {                  # We're seeing it the second time
      now = mktime(ts)      # Keep track of the current log time 
      rt = now - x[r];      # Compute the delta
      delete (x[r])         # We don't need it any more
      # printf "Record <%s> has response time %f\n", r, rt;  # Print it out if you'd like
      hourrt += rt;         # Add it to this hour's total response time
      num++;                # And also keep track of how many records we have ending in this hour
       if (now % 3600 == 0) {  # Have we switched to a new hour?
          printf "Average response time = %f\n", hourrt / num;   # Dump the average
          num = hourrt = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You will need to invoke this script as follows:

```
gawk -v UIDFILE=name_of_uid_file  -f scriptname.awk
```

Comment: Thanks Ram for your suggestions. Yes, I agree as I am new to scripting so you might see novice style in code. I am using on GNU AWK. I will try this and let you know the outcome

Comment: Hi Ram, I am facing issue while running this code. I have made up this test.awk and command m using is : awk -f test.awk test.log > output.log

Comment: actually I am using another awk to get uid in the log file and putting them in array. So while using ur awk I am not able to pass these uid to your awk.                                           here is code to get uid                                      uids=`cat $i|grep "Service" |awk 'BEGIN {FS="lt;";RS ="gt;"} {print $2;}'| sort -u`

Comment: Do you then want to have only those uids (i.e., the result of the command that terminates in `| sort -u`) be the ones you look for in the log file? In other words, its those uids for which you want the average response time. Correct?

Comment: Correct Ram. Why I went with this because these logs contains embedded xml files and I am taking out the uids from that xmls. Hope I am making things clear. Thanks !

Comment: So your `sort -u` command produces a file with UIDs. Do you have thousands of UIDs? Millions? 100s of millions?

Comment: cat $i|grep "Service" |awk 'BEGIN {FS="lt;";RS ="gt;"} {print $2;}'| sort -u   This command creates array of uids with 2 million of records.

Comment: Edited script ... lmk how it goes, and please upvote if it helped you.

Comment: Thanks Ram I will try and will let you know

Comment: Hi Ram, I tried but this command didnt work, { gawk -v UIDFILE=uidfile.log -f avg-res-time.awk test.log } test.log is the main log which has all the xml formats with time stamps and uids, udifile.log is the file with uids extracted from test.log

Comment: Also I wanted to understand how you are trying to get timestamp from the log file for given uid.

Comment: UIDFILE must contain the output of your command ending in `sort -u`. Each line should be a single UID. Is this true? Next, the awk script assumes that `test.log` contains lines, each with the format: `2012-06-04 13:04:19,324 UNIQID1` (but you say test.log is in XML format?) The awk script uses the `mktime` built-in function to parse the timestamp into the seconds since epoch start. Using `mktime` allows you to compute time deltas in seconds. The most probable reason for the script not working is because one/some of these assumptions are being violated. Have you tried it on a small test case?

Comment: Yes, True in UID FIle, each line is single UID. Yes Format is as follows, [2013-04-03 08:54:19,989 INFO [LOGGER] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><event><body>&amp;lt;UId&amp;gt;904c-be-4e-bbda-3e62&amp;lt;/UId&amp;gt;&amp;lt;</body></event>]

Comment: the above xml, date timestamp in one line

Comment: Apologies for the delay. The script I provided is tied to the format I assumed. If you are still interested in this approach, let me know and perhaps we can do this over email or github.

Comment: Hey, No need to apologize, you are helping me out. I will message you my mail id. Thanks